# Correct Use of "to train somebody in something" in a sentence

Tags: semantics

Is

> We would like to train 2 of our employees in Arabic language

correct? Does it mean we want them (2 of the employees) to learn the Arabic language in an Arabic language training?

Comment: No, but only because 'in Arabic language' should be 'in Arabic' or (more fussily) 'in the Arabic language'.

Comment: If emphasising that they will actually attend a course (rather than informal learning): "*We would like 2 of our employees to attend Arabic language training*"

Comment: *To train somebody in Arabic* can mean **either** 'to teach them Arabic' **or** 'to train them, using lessons/classes in Arabic'. It is not clear which is intended. In the first case it would be clearer to say, "We would like to teach two of our employees Arabic"; and in the second case, "We would like to train two of our Arabic-speaking employees."

Comment: It is confusing whether Arabic is the medium of training, or it points to 'Arabic language' training.

Comment: It is confusing whether Arabic is the medium of training, or it points to 'Arabic language' training.